# With node-cache, not able to get the data after set using Firebase as the backend

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, rest, caching

I am building my own backend API, with Firebase as the backend, so I want to cache using `node-cache`, but after I set the cache which should give me a truthy value, for me to get the cache response it keep giving me undefined.

Here is my caching class:

```js
import {injectable} from "inversify";
import * as NodeCache from "node-cache";
import {SearchDataFile} from "../../searching/domain/search_domian";


@injectable()
class Caching {
  private myCache:NodeCache;
  constructor() {
    this.myCache = new NodeCache({stdTTL: 7000, checkperiod: 120});
  }
  public get(key: string): SearchDataFile | undefined {
    return this.myCache.get(key);
  }

  public checkKeyAvailable(keyValue: string): boolean {
    return this.myCache.has(keyValue);
  }
  public set(key: string, data: SearchDataFile): boolean {
    return this.myCache.set(key, data, 3600);
  }
  public delete(key: string): string[] | undefined {
    return this.myCache.take(key);
  }
}

export default Caching;
```

This is where I am using it:

```js
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable object-curly-spacing */
import {FirebaseUser} from "../../authentication/domain/userEntity";
import {SearchDataFile} from "../domain/search_domian";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {SearchServicesRepository} from "./crednetials/searchRepository";
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import Caching from "../../core/application/cache";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

@injectable()
export class SearchServiceImplementation implements SearchServicesRepository {
  constructor(@inject(Caching) private caching: Caching ) {}

  async getAlldata(): Promise<SearchDataFile> {
    const valueCheck = this.caching.get("allData");
    logger.debug(`the checking ==== ${valueCheck}`);
    if (valueCheck != undefined) {
      logger.debug(`the checking after check ==== ${valueCheck}`);
      //  const cachedDataFromDB:SearchDataFile = this.caching.get("allData") as SearchDataFile;
      return valueCheck;
    }
    const usersData = await admin.firestore().collection("users").get();
    const firbaseusers:FirebaseUser[] = usersData.docs.map((users)=> {
      const userData = users.data() as FirebaseUser;
      return userData;
    });
    const data:SearchDataFile = {
      users: firbaseusers,
      community: [],
      library: [],
      news: [],
      forum: [],
    };
    const value =this.caching.set("allData", data);
    logger.debug(`getAllData ${value}`);
    return data;
  }


  async search(searchTerm: string): Promise<SearchDataFile> {
    const valueCheck = this.caching.checkKeyAvailable("allData");
    logger.debug(`the checking if data is store in cache ${valueCheck}`);
    if (valueCheck) {
      const cachedDataFromDB:SearchDataFile = this.caching.get("allData") as SearchDataFile;
      logger.debug(`the data is store in cache ${cachedDataFromDB}`);
      const filteredUsers = cachedDataFromDB.users.filter((user) =>
        user.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
      return {
        users: filteredUsers,
        community: [],
        library: [],
        news: [],
        forum: [],
      };
    }
    const usersData = await admin.firestore().collection("users").get();
    const firbaseusers:FirebaseUser[] = usersData.docs.map((users)=> {
      const userData = users.data() as FirebaseUser;
      return userData;
    });
    const filteredUsers = firbaseusers.filter((user) =>
      user.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    );
    return {
      users: filteredUsers,
      community: [],
      library: [],
      news: [],
      forum: [],
    };
  }
}
```

where i am using the class `SearchServicesRepository`

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import {myContainer} from "../../core/inversify_config";
import {TYPES} from "../../core/types";
import {SearchServicesRepository} from "../infastructure/crednetials/searchRepository";

export async function getAllFromDB(req: Request, res: Response,) {
  try {
    const getAllData = myContainer.get<SearchServicesRepository>(TYPES.SearchServicesRepository);
    const data = await getAllData.getAlldata();
    return res.status(200).send({message: "Succesfull", data});
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
}
```

Here are the related Functions logs:

[image: Logs from Google Cloud Console]

Comment: Can you add the code where you define and export the Cloud Function? (the part where you actually use the `SearchServiceImplementation` class)

Comment: okay, adding now @samthecodingman

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to also bring in any code related to `myContainer` too as its unclear what it does in `../../core/inversify_config`.

Comment: that is just to bind class... just dependencies injections stuff @samthecodingman